# Smooth scroll (locomotive scroll) and scroll triggered animation (framer motion + react-intersection-observer) bug

Tags: reactjs, smooth-scrolling, framer-motion, locomotive-scroll, react-intersection-observer

How can we make smooth scroll from locomotive scroll and scroll triggered animations (with framer motion and react-intersection-observer) coexist ?
I've made a very basic codesandbox with smooth scroll enabled and a small animation scroll triggered and as you can see the animation is very "buggy" (to see it, you have to open the codesandbox browser in a new window, if not, the smooth scroll doesn't work - and the animations works fine) :
https://codesandbox.io/s/smooth-scroll-framer-motion-8z5u8s?file=/src/App.js

Maybe I implemented locomotive scroll in a bad way ? Maybe I did something wrong with the animation ? Maybe it's simply impossible ? You tell me :)

Cheers

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Currently trying to integrate react locomotive scroll with framer motion and I have scroll triggered animations with framer motion and it's very buggy (flickers like crazy when scrolling).